# aws sync s3 Windows Scheduled Task Returning 0x1

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, windows-task-scheduler

I have created a windows scheduled task to run an `aws` command to sync a local folder to an S3 bucket. The task runs a .bat file. If the .bat is ran manually, it runs fine. When it is run via the task I get a 0x1 as the last run result.

Following advice found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015669/aws-s3-command-does-not-work-in-a-batch-file-triggered-by-a-windows-task-schedul), my bat file looks like this:

```
set AWS_CONFIG_FILE=C:\Users\xxx\.aws\config
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx
aws s3 sync "C:\my_local_folder" s3://my_bucket --delete
```

`xxx` in `set AWS_CONFIG_FILE=C:\Users\xxx\.aws\config` is the correct path to the `.aws\config` folder.

My task looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The account being used is an admin account, is already successfully running other scheduled tasks and the paths in the task are correct.

Comment: Are you sure that the batch file is being executed? Have you tried redirecting output to a file to determine the error being generated? See: [Redirecting Error Messages from Command Prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/110930)

Comment: Thank you @JohnRotenstein this is very useful it comes back with `'aws' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` Problem solved! I need to put the full path to aws.exe

Comment: Great! Alternatively, you could put the AWS directory [into your PATH variable](http://superuser.com/questions/737542/how-can-i-add-a-program-path-to-the-windows-environment-variables-for-easy-comma).

Answer (score 2):

Courtesy @JohnRotenstein's comment about redirecting output, I changed the command to be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\aws.exe" s3 sync "C:\my_local_folder" s3://my_bucket --delete
```